# HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath on Azure

Tags: c#, file, azure

Suppose I have something like this:

```
string TheFile = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath + "\\SomeDir\\" + TheFilename + ".js";
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(TheFile , SomeText);
```

This works on my local machine: the file is created and visible in the file system and in the solution explorer. If I deploy on Azure, is the file going to be written only on the instance that's running this code or will it be written and available on all other instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you write to Azure Drive or some equivalent thereof the change will of course be limited to the instance filesystem. The instance filesystem changes will be lost if the VM crashes and also in some other cases, so whatever you need to preserve should be stored to durable storage such as Azure Blob Storage.